# 4 step process problem

Tags: usability, process

The thing is that i'm working in some kind of social media app and the client request one of the "parts?" (the main btw) to be a 4 step process, just 4.

So right now we have this

1- Search for a place and

2- Take a photo (or skip this step)

3- Apply some kind of filter

4- Edit a few more little things and publish the thing.

The problem is that my dev's team can't do a custom camera, we are using just native cameras for this (don't ask me why), so the camera can't have that "skip" button.
I proposed an intermediate popup wich could say something like "want to take a pic?" and "skip", but this is adding another step, so in this way we are having 5 instead of 4.

Please, give me your thoughts in this, my stone of the day.

Comment: Not sure if this question will be closed before it's answered, but what would the user do if they skip step 2? Do they otherwise select another photo on their device?

Comment: No, the app will bring the default pic of the place (we are taking them from facebook).
So you have just two options, use the default pic or take one.

Comment: I need to solve the cannot-make-custom-cam issue and respect a 4 step process

Comment: What about displaying the camera as a thumbnail alongside with the thumbs downloaded from Facebook?

Comment: @DominikOslizlo I don't understand, have you got any example?

Comment: @FedeCrespo, if you are still interested in answers, try to stick to the rules of this site: Basically what you say is: We need five steps to be able to skip taking a photo, but the requirements demand four steps. This is not a user experience problem but a project management or implementation problem. If you think you have a valid question for this site please add some examples, wireframes, screens etc. of the project so it is possible to make some recommendations how to keep a good (enough) user experience while keeping four steps and adding the skip option.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get you the steps sorted out:

1.Search Screen: where you search and select a place.

2.Pic Screen: Where you load facebook photo by default and ask user to change that by giving camera option and Next button will be there by default[means user can skip this step]

3.Edit screen:Where user edits[Apply filter, put text etc] the photo taken via camera app or the default photo from the facebook.

4.Preview and Publish screen: Where user sees his final output and publish the picture.

If you put the steps as screens your confusion will be solved. It is always a good practice to sketch down a wireframe and put description of the functionality which goes where to avoid such problems.

I suggest you give the skip option for edit photo also. It decrease the loop completion time as some people may not edit their photos.